# Change placeholder text on change event via select

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've got an issue that I've been trying to sort but can't quite do the last bit and have been going round in circles.

Basically I have a search box with a select box before the search input area, depending on which item is chosen from the drop down box I want the placeholder text to change in the search input area. Now I've managed to get this working in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G4GvT/

However this is using the value attribute so when you enter text to the search area it adds to it rather that starts fresh as when using placeholder. I've tried changing the value to placeholder but still no luck, and also using the .attr rather than .val:

```
$('#search-type').change(function() {
    $('#search-query').attr(this.placeholder);
});
```

If anybody could give me a hand I'd be very grateful, I know it should be quite easy but can't work out where I am going wrong.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/G4GvT/3/

```
$('#search-type').change(function() {
    $('#search-query').prop('placeholder',$(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

some html changes in above example jsfiddle

remove the value attr of text box and add placeholder attr. so that you can check the proper out reflecting in the text box.

http://jsfiddle.net/gvFy9/

You can also do like this.

```
$('#search-type').change(function() {
    $('#search-query').attr('placeholder',$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer as well Skparwal, it's appreciated.